# What is the story behind Tradehill?

Tags: exchanges, websites, history, payment, tradehill

[Tradehill](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/TradeHill) used to be an important Bitcoin exchange, but it was [closed earlier this year](http://tradehillblog.com/2012/02/13/tradehill-suspending-trading-and-returning-client-funds/) due to losing a lot of money to their payment processor. What is the full story behind Tradehill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Dwolla promised that they would never honor chargebacks. They in fact did and stole dollars back from their bank account after TH gave Bitcoins to the scammers. They lost *a lot of money* by this. I believe Dwolla is being sued for 2 million dollars as a result of this.

Comment: That isn't really "the full story behind Tradehill".

Comment: If you believe something is incorrect you may downvote or even vote for deletion. Please do not flag things for moderator attention based on correctness.